# Intro paragraph for blog posts with an intro doesn’t fit into page

Tags: bug, design, blog, responsive-design

Blog posts with an intro paragraph have some trimming on the left and right if the screen is narrow.

One example: the link from the profile page of a suspended account

> [image: Suspended]

refers to [Stack Overflow Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) and the text doesn't fit into screen:

> [image: Too wide]

The rest of page looks fine.

Comment: I think this happens on all blog posts that have an intro like that when viewed on a suitably small screen.

Comment: That blog post was written 14 years ago and probably migrated between three different content management systems so you can hopefully excuse it. Turn your phone sideways, voila!

Comment: FWIW the problem is probably `.gs64 { margin: -32px; }`, but really... turn your phone sideways, just like you would on any other web site that has CSS not perfectly adapted to your phone's dimensions.

Comment: @Stuck well it's a pretty big bug in the responsive design of the blog. It should take into account posts without intro, and it's not.